# How to graph/plot 2D Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG) function in MATLAB or python?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, plot, laplacianofgaussian

[image]

Hello.

I am trying to make a 3-D graph similar to the one below, that illustrates the 2-D Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG) function. How can I accomplish this through MATLAB or python? Code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

I have found that we can plot the gaussian using [this method](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/180778-plotting-a-3d-gaussian-function-using-surf), but I am looking for how to plot the laplacian of gaussian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the discrete laplacian function `del2`:

```
N = 3;
x=linspace(-N, N,30);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,x);
z=del2((1000/sqrt(2*pi).*exp(-(X.^2/2)-(Y.^2/2))));
surf(X,Y,z);
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: If you use `mesh` then the plot will be the same as the one in OPs question. Nice viridis BTW ;)

Comment: @CrisLuengo nah, I can spot a viridis when I see one! That vivid green and yellow must be from viridis! [Look at parula](https://i.imgur.com/0i8IW9f.png)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm using octave, and indeed viridis is the default colormap since 4.2 !

Comment: @obchardon that I didn't know! I am happy Octave went for that one and not parula!

Answer (score 1):

Using `del2` applied to a Gaussian one obtains an approximation to the true Laplacian function (it uses a discrete approximation to the derivative). This is not necessary, we can easily compute the expression for the second derivative of the Gaussian, and use that.

First we define a 1D Gaussian:

```matlab
x = linspace(-4,4,41);
G = exp(-x.^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi);
```

Next, we compute the 2nd derivative of the 1D Gaussian:

```matlab
Gxx = G .* (x.^2-1);
```

The Gaussian has a nice property that you can multiply two 1D functions together to get the 2D function. Thus,

```matlab
data = G .* Gxx.';
```

is the 2nd derivative along the y-axis of a 2D Gaussian. The transposed of `data` is the 2nd derivative along the x-axis.

The Laplace is defined as the sum of partial derivatives along each axis:

```matlab
data = data + data.';
```

Plotting this leads to (I tried replicating the point of view of the original graph also):

[image: Laplace of Gaussian]

Here's the full code:

```matlab
x = linspace(-4,4,41);
G = exp(-x.^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi);
Gxx = G .* (x.^2-1);
data = G .* Gxx.';
data = data + data.';
surf(x,x,data,'facecolor','white')
view(45,13)
set(gca,'dataaspectratio',[1,1,0.08])
grid off
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
```